# Mocking a file containing JSON data with mock.patch and mock_open

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I'm trying to test a method that requires the use of `json.load` in Python 3.6.
And after several attempts, I tried running the test "normally" (with the usual unittest.main() from the CLI), and in the iPython REPL.

Having the following function (simplified for purpose of the example)

```
def load_metadata(name):
    with open("{}.json".format(name)) as fh:
        return json.load(fh)
```

with the following test:

```
class test_loading_metadata(unittest2.TestCase):
    @patch('builtins.open', new_callable=mock_open(read_data='{"disabled":True}'))
    def test_load_metadata_with_disabled(self, filemock):
        result = load_metadata("john")
        self.assertEqual(result,{"disabled":True})
        filemock.assert_called_with("john.json")
```

The result of the execution of the test file, yields a heart breaking:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'MagicMock'
```

While executing the same thing in the command line, gives a successful result.

I tried in several ways (patching with `with`, as decorator), but the only thing that I can think of, is the `unittest` library itself, and whatever it might be doing to interfere with mock and patch.

Also checked versions of python in the virtualenv and ipython, the versions of `json` library.

I would like to know why what looks like the same code, works in one place
and doesn't work in the other.
Or at least a pointer in the right direction to understand why this could be happening.

Comment: Your title and your question don't seem to be related all that much otherwise. What function are you talking about? Is the class the unittest? The issue here has nothing to do with methods or functions otherwise.

Comment: If you had a test *function* that *worked*, then you forgot to share that, and you were probably not using `new_callable` or had wrapped the callable in a lambda. It would not have been the exact same `patch(...)` configuration.

Comment: I forgot to share the test _function_. Sorry for that. I checked it again, and you are right, it was a slightly different patch config.
Thanks for the corrections to the question as well. I'm so tired I'm not even writing straight.

Comment: Time to get yourself some sleep then, you'll be much more productive afterwards. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`json.load()` simply calls `fh.read()`, but `fh` is not a `mock_open()` object. It's a `mock_open()()` object, because `new_callable` is *called* before patching to create the replacement object:

```
>>> from unittest.mock import patch, mock_open
>>> with patch('builtins.open', new_callable=mock_open(read_data='{"disabled":True}')) as filemock:
...     with open("john.json") as fh:
...         print(fh.read())
...
<MagicMock name='open()().__enter__().read()' id='4420799600'>
```

Don't use `new_callable`, you don't want your `mock_open()` object to be called! Just pass it in as the `new` argument to `@patch()` (this is also the second positional argument, so you can leave off the `new=` here):

```
@patch('builtins.open', mock_open(read_data='{"disabled":True}'))
def test_load_metadata_with_disabled(self, filemock):
```

at which point you can call `.read()` on it when used as an `open()` function:

```
>>> with patch('builtins.open', mock_open(read_data='{"disabled":True}')) as filemock:
...     with open("john.json") as fh:
...         print(fh.read())
...
{"disabled":True}
```

The `new` argument is the object that'll replace the original when patching. If left to the default, `new_callable()` is used instead. You don't want `new_callable()` here.